# What does [$\hat{x}, \hat{p_{x}}$] mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

In an article it is given that [$\hat{x}, \hat{p_{x}}$] is equal to $\hat{x}\hat{p_{x}} - \hat{p_{x}}\hat{x}$. What does this mean?

Comment: That's the *definition* of the commutator. I'm not sure what there is to explain. Also, please give *actual references* instead of "in an article" when you are referring to something.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the **commutator** between $\hat{p_x}$ and $\hat{x}$. It means applying the operator $\hat{p_x}$ and then the operator $\hat{x}$, *minus* the other way around. If it's different from zero it means that the order in which you apply these 2 operators matters. If it's equal to zero, you say that two operators *commute*, and you can change the order anytime.

Extending the answer, on behalf of user CountTo10. Commutators are really important in QM, not only are they related to the simmultaneous measuring of different observables (via uncertainty relations), but they also inform about the conservation of a given observable.

In the Heisenberg picture we have:

$$
i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} \hat A = [\hat A, \hat H].
$$

which means that an observable that commutes with the *Hamiltonian* of the system is therefore conserved (because the right hand side of the equation would be zero).

Comment: +1 you were 5 minutes ahead of me, would you consider extending your answer by two lines to include the importance of commutators involving  $\hat H $ in particular.? Just a thought.....